# App Engine Datastore - how to simply store and update a single value with Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've gone through the google app engine documentation and it's really not very easy to grasp the things that they talk about there. I've started coding a new app, and already following a High Replication Datastore example. Saving multiple entities in a group, and be able to query them and show them on my jsp web pages. My question is how to save a single value and then update it later when needed. Basically, I need to save the maximum ID I've given so far. Then, when I need to add a new entity to the group, I simply need to read this single maximum ID value, and increment it by 1, and save the incremented value back. Finally, I need to assign the incremented value to my new entity as its ID.

I need to mention that, I'm coding with Java servlets and JSP. So, Python code is not useful for me. My existing code piece is the following. The line "long ID = getNewID();" is supposed to give me this incremented value and also put the incremented value back to the datastore. I'd appreciate any help for coding the getNewID() method.

```
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    Key doctorTableKey = KeyFactory.createKey("doctorTable", "doctorTableName");
    Entity doctor = new Entity("doctorEntity", doctorTableKey);

    long ID = getNewID();
    String ID = getNewID(datastore, doctor);
    if(ID != -1){
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String lastname = req.getParameter("lastname");

        doktor.setProperty("ID", ID);
        doktor.setProperty("name", name);
        doktor.setProperty("lastname", lastname);
        doktor.setProperty("city", req.getParameter("city"));

        datastore.put(doctor);
        resp.sendRedirect("/doctorAdd.jsp?name=" + name + " " + lastname);
    }else{
        resp.sendRedirect("/doctorAdd.jsp?name=ERROR!!!!");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't set your own IDs with a counter. AppEngine's datastore will automatically assign an ID to your entities when they're first inserted, if you don't provide one. The problem with using a counter is that this is a central point that every insert will have to touch; and App Engine is not designed for scaling to high frequency writes to the same entity groups (different entity groups are no problem). Indeed, they recommend no more than about one write per second, on average, per entity group.

In short, a fixed counter will kill your performance. Use app engine's default ID assignment system unless you have a pressing reason otherwise. Note that app engine's IDs are not sequential, for precisely the reason that sequential IDs don't scale.

Comment: Can you point me to a documentation or simple example codes (other than code.google.com pages)?

Comment: I'll use this ID in another entity group. In the original entity group, I'll have the information about the doctors. In the second entity group, I'll have the operations that the doctor has performed. So, the ID in the second entity group will point to a doctor in the first entity group. This is kind of making it a relational database in the datastore. Is this a good design?

Comment: @newwebdev, you shouldn't have a finite, fixed set of entity groups; this again will kill performance. Creating entity groups is a very cheap operation. For example, you could have every doctor be the root of an entity group, and have all operations performed by the doctor be in the same entity group. Then you could have a sequential counter for _within this entity group_. So you could, say, have operation #13 for doctor X. But having a single global counter for all doctors is a bad idea.

Comment: And there's still very little point in having a sequential counter in the first place in nearly all situations. Just let App Engine assign your IDs for you.